# custom UIView and loadNibNamed not working

Tags: ios, ios6

I am trying to create a custom UIView and have it load in a xib file. The custom UIView is called JtView and here is the code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    NSLog(@"initWithFrame was called");  // this was called
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:NULL];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
  [super awakeFromNib];
  [self addSubview:self.view];
}
```

In creating the xib file (File -> New -> File -> User Interface -> View), I deleted out the main Window and dragged a View from Xcode's object pallette. I tried alt-dragging to the header for JtView but this wasn't working. Do I need to create an association here or should I just leave what XCode created in place? (edit - see comments below for further clarification)

I have also added a UILabel to the xib.

However, when I run in simulator and set the background color to red, the label is not showing up. Do I need to create the UILabel as a reference in the custom UIView? Should I be deleting this or leaving it in place? [image]

thx

**edit 1**
Here's a screenshot of the connections and the header file:

Comment: Please check file's owner of the View in nib file. You must mention JtView in place of file owner of view in nib

Comment: so yes, I've adjusted and not deleted out the main `Window`. I've hooked up the file's owner to the View but the label is still not showing up.

Comment: okay. If you have not yet solved your problem please refer to Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144482/custom-uiview-iboutlet-not-set/15154855#15154855 It might be helpful. Please revert to me in case of any problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solve it adding a class method to the UIView:

---

```
+ (id)customView;
```

---

```
+ (id)customView
{
    CustomView *customView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];

    // make sure customView is not nil or the wrong class!
    if ([customView isKindOfClass:[CustomView class]])
        return customView;
    else
        return nil;
}
```

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CustomView *customView = [CustomView customView];
    //And where you gonna use it add this line:
    //this self.view refers to any view (scrollView, cellView...)
    [self.view addSubview:customView];
}
```

---

I hope it´s gonna help

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    NSArray *obj = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:obj[0]];
}
```

Or if you have an @property IBOutlet named "nibview" you could do:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.nibview];
}
```

Comment: This code is giving me a crash saying `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2)`!

Comment: Which version did you try?

Comment: XCode - 5.1(B)
iOS - 7.1

Comment: Is there a nib named "MyView.xib" in your project? If you set a breakpoint on the second line, what does obj[0] contain?

Comment: I changed the nib name to my own xib file and I haven't checked the code.