# Custom UIView iboutlet not set

Tags: iphone, ios

I have created a custom UIView class named "abc" and a nib with it. Created a UIButton in IB in that nib. Now when I try to create outlet of that UIButton by extending arrow to File's Owner it wont allow me to do so. Please tell What i am doing wrong

Comment: change the class name in identity spector of your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem might be you are not setting Custom Class name for "abc" in xib file. Please not that whenever you create a subclass of UIView. You have to bind its view with that class. And when you are going to make IBOutlet connection instead of connecting it to File's Owner you have to connect it to you View placed in Objects(object list is on left side in interface builder).

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the view of your nib file to the `customView` class name, in the Identity Inspector, change the `UIView` Class in the picture to your custom class

[image: identity inspector]

Answer (score -1):

*) Goto the views xib

*) Click on the File's Owner Identity inspector

*) and change the class name to the name of the View yu want.